# Full Calendar event render, jQuery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to edit events on full calendar? For the moment I see only texts on the events but what I want to do is to import pictures also, so it should have Name, Profession, Date. I tried to edit it via prepend jQuery, so I wrote

```
$(element).find('.fc-title').prepend('<div class="example" ></div>');
```

and when I drag the event into it it should remove the date from there and show it inside event div

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `eventRender: function(event, element) {` functionality. Then you can access / modify the titles HTML like this:

```
element.find('.fc-title').html();
```

Here you'll be able to add images in, or render HTML that was added.

This is added to the calendar like:

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar({
   weekends: false,
   eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.find('.fc-title').html('<div class="example"></div>');
   }
});
```

Comment: i used this, its ok but i need the cells to expand when droping the event , so it should show everything that contains the event itself, because of the date it shows only the half of the event,

Comment: You could try adding: `contentHeight: 'auto',` to the calendar settings. That might help solve it, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update your CSS for '.fc-title'

Either:

`element.find('.fc-title').css({ 'white-space:': 'normal !important' });`

or CSS:

`.fc-title {
    white-space: normal !important;
  }`